# send email when Saltstack gets errors

Tags: salt-stack

is there any way to send error notification on email, when Saltstack gets error when trying to install certain packages on minions, for example if i tried to install vim or any other package on fifty minion, and only two of them returns error, is there any way to send notification about this error on email?

Answer (score 1):

Please look into the Salt Reactor [docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/index.html) and check [this guide](https://codehammer.io/blog/post/saltstack-highstate-email-alerts/). Hope it helps.

Comment: Please post the solution here instead of linking to external websites.